# Access to clipboard for Chrome extension using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome Extension. Every time the user copies something, my extension should capture the copied text. 
I read that access to the clipboard is a security concern. However there is a clipboardRead and clipboardWrite permission according to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions

Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in the link you posted that the permission is used with document.execCommand('paste'), you could easily write a function to monitor changes in the clipboard, and then do more when you find it was modified since the last check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.execCommand('paste');
document.execCommand('copy');
document.execCommand('cut');
```

to interact with the clipboard.

I think you can find the documentation here (for firefox, at least): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 0):

You need to trap the copy action event, and then read the clipboard in a background page. These answers should help:

[Google Chrome Extensions: How to detect Copy action (Ctrl-C and Edit-Copy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870369/google-chrome-extensions-how-to-detect-copy-action-ctrl-c-and-edit-copy)

[How to read the Clipboard text in google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509670/how-to-read-the-clipboard-text-in-google-chrome-extension/43374989#43374989)